# ac-dcd auto-completion don't work for dub packages out of box

Tags: windows, emacs, d, code-completion, dub

Using GNU Emacs 24.4 on Windows.

Can't get autocompletion for vibe.d package even for "empty project", just "dub init" with vibe.d in AppData/Roaming/dub.
Autocompletion for std works great! (after dcd.conf file in $HOME/dcd.conf).

Comment: My guess is that DCD can't find vibed source files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to edit your `dcd.conf` file and add every folder of the vibe repository that contains some ***.d** sources:

- core
- crypto
- data
- etc...

then restart DCD-server.